# How can I write braces, { and }, in Emacs on Mac OS X with a scandinavian keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard, emacs, keyboard-layout, latin1

I can not write `{` and `}` in Emacs on my Macbook Air with a Swedish keyboard layout. In all other programs I do this by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>(</kbd> for `{` and the corresponding keys with <kbd>)</kbd> for `}`.

How can I type `{` and `}` in emacs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer on StackOverflow.com:

[Unable to type braces and square braces in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376863/unable-to-type-braces-and-square-braces-in-emacs/3378391#3378391)

```
(setq mac-option-modifier nil
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

Comment: This works well for Emacs app

Comment: or [this one so answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13123970/1806019) only affect the right tab

Answer (score 2):

You likely have this problem in all command-line applications and even your shell.

Disable *Use Option as Meta key* in *Terminal » Preferences » Settings » Keyboard*.

---

This might be a problem for you, so other options are key remapping solutions, utility applications like [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) where you can define key sequences and map them on self-defined hotkeys, or changing your keyboard using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele).

Comment: this works for emacs launched by the command line, but you lose the use of alt as meta and have to type e.g. esc-x instea of M-X

Comment: @mico That's why *this might be a problem for you*. You need to choose an option here. Workarounds are Esc for Meta, or changing the keyboard layout. (Or, well, Emacs.app :-) )

Answer (score 2):

I tried fondling with my keypad and found out that ctrl + alt + 8 or 9 works for curly brackets { or }

Comment: fondling sounds creepy.

Answer (score 0):

I installed an English keyboard and changed my keyboard to English. Then press shift + Å + ^