# How do I quit telnet without using standard Ctrl+] combination?

Tags: macos, telnet

The title says it all. Note that I'm using a non-US layout, Norwegian, so I can't create the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> combination. I've found the trick before, but can't find it.

Comment: With french keyboard, on mac OsX, type ctrl + $
then type quit...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not sure what layout you have, but for me in Finnish layout it is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>å</kbd>.

Comment: with Finnish layout and on Mac OS X it seems to be ctrl + ¨. Thanks for hinting me to right direction.

Comment: with German layout and on Mac OS X it seems to be ctrl + ü

Comment: Spanish layout: ctrl + '+'

Comment: Same for Swedish keyboard!

Comment: Same for Norwegian (CTRL+Å)

Answer (score 37):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to enter the telnet menu, then enter `quit`. For more commands, see `man telnet`.

**Edit:** Haven't noticed that you can't type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, but I would be surprised if there isn't a way to type that with every keyboard. But you can change the escape character with the commandline option `-e [char]`.

Comment: I tried with -e y earlier, typing ctrl+y didn't work.

Comment: @trygvis: Found out why it didn't work: `-e y` makes the `y` key the escape key. To use `Ctrl+y` you have to use `-e ^y` (that is the circumflex character).

Comment: Ah, doh. Thanks! Ctrl-å is the easiest for me (less to type), but very nice to know anyway. Cheers!

Comment: not all keyboard layouts contain "common" symbols. For example [Italian keyboard lacks `~` and backtick](https://superuser.com/q/667622/241386), [French keyboard lacks `@`](https://askubuntu.com/q/280492/253474) which sometimes makes programming almost impossible on inconvenient without changing layout. In this case [Finnish keyboard has no brackets](https://mooselander.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/brackets-on-a-swedish-keyboard/). [German keyboard](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-can-i-type-square-brackets-in-workspaces-on-a-german-keyboard-using-mac), too

Comment: [Swedish keyboards](https://superuser.com/q/240994/241386) faces the same problem

Answer (score 7):

To answer your specific question: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>å</kbd>  then enter `quit`.

But to make it more fun it depends on your layout a lot:

*(Remember on a Mac <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is your <kbd>⌃</kbd> key)*

- Default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- Dutch, Belgian: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd>
- French: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>
- Finnish, Swedish, Norwegian, Danish: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>å</kbd>
- Swiss: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>¨</kbd>
- German: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd>
- Hungarian and Turkish: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
- Portuguese: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd>
- Canadian French: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ç</kbd>

then enter `quit`.

For more commands, see `man telnet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command "set escape" followed by any key you want to set the escape character.

example: `telnet> set escape` <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

I often don't remember the key-sequences... except at the telnet prompt this sequence works:
telnet> quit

followed by the return key.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> (back to telnet) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (back to shell)

... helped me on following constellation

- AWS Web Terminal (in Firefox)
- Mac OS
- German keyboard layout

Answer (score -3):

With UK keyboard is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>